Why do I get ( Can't parse 'pt1'. ) when running image prcessing algorithm on video using python?
I am trying to run lane detection using hough transform on python
and
I keep getting the follow error:

Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
on line 47 ,

corresponding to this line:
 cv2.line(line_image, (int(x1), int(y1)), (int(x2), int(y2)), (255, 0, 0), 10)

I am also getting this error:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object
line 6, in make_points
    slope, intercept = line
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Video format is 720x1280 (720p)
This is the entire code
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_points(image, line):
    slope, intercept = line
    y1 = int(image.shape[0])# bottom of the image
    y2 = int(y1*3/5)         # slightly lower than the middle
    x1 = int((y1 - intercept)/slope)
    x2 = int((y2 - intercept)/slope)
    return [[x1, y1, x2, y2]]

def average_slope_intercept(image, lines):
    left_fit    = []
    right_fit   = []
    if lines is None:
        return None
    for line in lines:
        for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
            fit = np.polyfit((x1,x2), (y1,y2), 1)
            slope = fit[0]
            intercept = fit[1]
            if slope < 0: # y is reversed in image
                left_fit.append((slope, intercept))
            else:
                right_fit.append((slope, intercept))
    # add more weight to longer lines
    left_fit_average  = np.average(left_fit, axis=0)
    right_fit_average = np.average(right_fit, axis=0)
    left_line  = make_points(image, left_fit_average)
    right_line = make_points(image, right_fit_average)
    averaged_lines = [left_line, right_line]
    return averaged_lines

def canny(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    kernel = 5
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(kernel, kernel),0)
    canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150)
    return canny

def display_lines(img,lines):
    line_image = np.zeros_like(img)
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
                cv2.line(line_image, (int(x1), int(y1)), (int(x2), int(y2)), (255, 0, 0), 10)

    return line_image

def region_of_interest(canny):
    height = canny.shape[0]
    width = canny.shape[1]
    mask = np.zeros_like(canny)
    triangle = np.array([[
    (200, height),
    (800, 350),
    (1200, height),]], np.int32)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, triangle, 255)
    masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(canny, mask)
    return masked_image

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Video_City.mp4")
while(cap.isOpened()):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    canny_image = canny(frame)
    cropped_canny = region_of_interest(canny_image)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_canny, 2, np.pi/180, 100, np.array([]), minLineLength=40,maxLineGap=5)
    averaged_lines = average_slope_intercept(frame, lines)
    line_image = display_lines(frame, averaged_lines)
    combo_image = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 0.8, line_image, 1, 1)
    cv2.imshow("result", combo_image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


any idea how to fix this? I tried the algorithm on an image and it works just fine. I am not getting any video output.

Are you sure you have all the int() calls? From researching this error, it happens when the parameters aren't integers.

I do. I modified the fps of the video, but it does not show the output video for the entire duration.

The second error will happen if lines is empty in average_slope_intercept(). Then left_fit and right_fit will be empty, and np.average() returns a single nan value instead of averages of the slopes and intercepts.

To figure out the reason for the first error, put print(x1, y1, x2, y2) before the cv2.line() call. Then you'll see the values of all the variables right before the error happens.

How can I fix that?

Make sure lines is empty. if lines == []: return None

Maybe that's what you thought you were doing with if lines is None:?

You haven't shared the video file so I couldn't reproduce your exact issue. Instead, I've tried running your code on a different video used for lane detection and I encountered a similar exception.
One issue that immediately pops out is that in the funciton average_slope_intercept', it's possible that 'left_fit' or 'right_fit' lists to be empty, which causes make_points` to throw an exception. I've modified your code to address this and at least on my test video it works.
Here's your code with my changes:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_points(image, line):
    slope, intercept = line
    y1 = int(image.shape[0])  # bottom of the image
    y2 = int(y1 * 3 / 5)  # slightly lower than the middle
    x1 = int((y1 - intercept) / slope)
    x1 = min(max(x1, 0), image.shape[1])
    x2 = int((y2 - intercept) / slope)
    x2 = min(max(x2, 0), image.shape[1])
    return [[x1, y1, x2, y2]]



def average_slope_intercept(image, lines):
    left_fit    = []
    right_fit   = []
    if lines is None:
        return None
    for line in lines:
        for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
            fit = np.polyfit((x1,x2), (y1,y2), 1)
            slope = fit[0]
            intercept = fit[1]
            if slope < 0: # y is reversed in image
                left_fit.append((slope, intercept))
            else:
                right_fit.append((slope, intercept))
    # add more weight to longer lines
    if len(left_fit) > 0:
        left_fit_average = np.average(left_fit, axis=0)
        left_line = make_points(image, left_fit_average)
    else:
        left_line = None
    if len(right_fit) > 0:
        right_fit_average = np.average(right_fit, axis=0) if len(right_fit) > 0 else 0
        right_line = make_points(image, right_fit_average)
    else:
        right_line = None

    averaged_lines = [left_line, right_line]
    return averaged_lines

def canny(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    kernel = 5
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(kernel, kernel),0)
    canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150)
    return canny

def display_lines(img,lines):
    line_image = np.zeros_like(img)
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:
            if line is not None:
                for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
                    cv2.line(line_image, (int(x1), int(y1)), (int(x2), int(y2)), (255, 0, 0), 10)

    return line_image

def region_of_interest(canny):
    height = canny.shape[0]
    width = canny.shape[1]
    mask = np.zeros_like(canny)
    triangle = np.array([[
    (200, height),
    (800, 350),
    (1200, height),]], np.int32)
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, triangle, 255)
    masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(canny, mask)
    return masked_image

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Video_City.mp4")
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    canny_image = canny(frame)
    cropped_canny = region_of_interest(canny_image)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_canny, 2, np.pi/180, 100, np.array([]), minLineLength=40, maxLineGap=5)
    averaged_lines = average_slope_intercept(frame, lines)
    line_image = display_lines(frame, averaged_lines)
    combo_image = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 0.8, line_image, 1, 1)
    cv2.imshow("result", combo_image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Hi, thank you for your response! I modified it accordingly and I ran into these errors: Traceback (most recent call last):
line 96, in 
line_image = display_lines(frame, averaged_lines)
File "\laneDetection.py", line 55, in display_lines
cv2.line(line_image, (int(x1), int(y1)), (int(x2), int(y2)), (255, 0, 0), 10)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'line'

Overload resolution failed:

Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
Can't parse 'pt1'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type



These are the videos I am trying to run it on: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1s9GLYRM_2qHJTIHh2rJ7c1P7q5A9lspM?usp=sharing . Could it possibly be from the videos themselves?? Size is 720p, format is jpg. I tried reducing the FPS to 25 yet it still loads video for a bit then crashes

the format of the videos are mp4, my bad.

@hmmm You're welcome. I've reproduced your issue using your videos. The thing is that make_points() returns points that are outside of the image. I added clamping to force the points to be inside the image, but it's a band-aid. You should understand why your algorithm suggests such points.
Also, I've added a check of the return value for cap.read() to exit gracefully when an empty image is returned
I've edited the code in my answer accordingly
